# Histogram overlay in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've got a plot which looks like this:

[image: plot]

I want it to stop overlaying. I've got code which creates the plots in a for-loop like this:

```
for column in columns:
    hist = df.hist(column=column)
    fig = hist.tolist()[0][0].get_figure()
    fig.savefig(f'blahblah/hists/{column}.png')
    del fig
    del hist
```

I've tried deleting the figure and histogram variables, but that doesn't work. How do I clear the plot and plot each one separately to its own separate file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Posting here to avoid [this problem](https://xkcd.com/979/). Matplotlib's plot needs to be cleared at the end of each for-loop.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then, at the end of each `for` loop,

```
plt.show()  # well, if you want to see it
plt.close()  # to clear the plot
```